# Parameter not passing through form?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to work with the django form validation walkthrough that they have [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/)

However, I seem to be getting stuck. It seem that one of my parameters (recipients) isn't being passed through, even though the others are.

Here is my html form:

```
<form action= "receiver" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label>
    <input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" /></p>
<p><label for="id_message">Message:</label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="id_message" /></p>
<p><label for="id_sender">Sender:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sender" id="id_sender" /></p>
<p><label for="id_recipients">Recipients:</label>
    <input type="text" name="recipients" id="id_recipients" /></p>
<p><label for="id_cc_myself">Cc myself:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cc_myself" id="id_cc_myself" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the relevant model class in models.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    recipients = MultiEmailField(required=True)
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

and here is the associated view:

```
def reciever(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data  
    print form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
            cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']      
            recipients = form.cleaned_data['recipients']
            template = loader.get_template('helloworld/receiver.html')

            context = RequestContext(request,{
                    'subject':subject,                          
                    'sender':sender,
                    'message': message,
                    'cc_myself': cc_myself,
                    'recipients': recipients,
        })
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request,{
            'form': form, 
        })
        template = loader.get_template('helloworld/wrong.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I don't get too much into the view, I can see from my print form that the request is invalid with the following output:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_subject">Subject:</label></th><td><input id="id_subject" maxlength="100" name="subject" type="text" value="slkj" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_message">Message:</label></th><td><input id="id_message" name="message" type="text" value="lkjqw" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_sender">Sender:</label></th><td><input id="id_sender" name="sender" type="text" value="ij@aol.com" /></td></tr>
**<tr><th><label for="id_recipients">Recipients:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_recipients" name="recipients" type="text" /></td></tr>**
<tr><th><label for="id_cc_myself">Cc myself:</label></th><td><input id="id_cc_myself" name="cc_myself" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
```

So for some reason, even though I do enter info into the form box (fake@aol.com), it doesn't seem to be passing through the form, and I'm not quite sure why.

Edit: sorry, I forgot an important part. I also added a custom class to the model.py as per the tutorial's instructions:

```
class MultiEmailField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        "Normalize data to a list of strings."

        # Return an empty list if no input was given.
        if not value:
            return []
        return value.split(',')

    def validate(self, value):
        "Check if value consists only of valid emails."

        # Use the parent's handling of required fields, etc.
        super(MultiEmailField, self).validate(value)

        for email in value:
            validate_email(email)
```

Comment: At least post what you claim to have typed in for the recipients.

Comment: And where is your MultiEmailField class?

Comment: Added them in! I just typed in an email. The recipient box can take in multiple emails separated by commas. What is defined as an email is validated by the django email validator, which I believe works, since sender is also an email required field and that tested OK

Comment: What do you get when you check on the `request.POST` keys? Also have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925278/using-cleaned-data-on-forms-in-django) on the use of `cleaned_data`