# Django call cleaned_data on all fields

Tags: django

Is there a way to call cleaned_data on all fields with some function instead of individually calling it for each field?

Also, why do we even need to call cleaned_data?

I am not sure if I need it here... I am using a for loop to save a formset, but it only saves the last one. Here is the code

```
for instance in form:
    tmp = instance.save(commit=False)
    # it throws an error when I try to do tmp[foreign_key] = other_model
    setattr(tmp, foreign_key, other_model) 
    tmp.save()
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925278/using-cleaned-data-on-forms-in-django

Comment: You *don't* ever need to call it. And that setattr call is utter nonsense: it's exactly equivalent to `tmp.fk = gen_house_form_saved`.

Comment: No it isn't. When I try that, it says tmp isn't modifiable...

Answer (score 1):

What are you hoping for? You don't ever call it. `cleaned_data` gets populated upon validating the form.

`form.is_valid()` populates `form.cleaned_data`, which is a dictionary storing all data "cleaned" i.e. validated and converted to their python types.

I don't think one can make data much more accessible than a dictionary of keys mapped to field names.

As for your latest update, that itself is pretty confusing.

You appear to be setting an attribute on a foreign key in your modelform instance based on a local variable named `'gen_house_form_saved'` (which I don't understand as well: if it's in the `locals()` namespace, and you're not using a dynamic name, why use `locals` at all).

Comment: Sorry I fixed that. I am filling in the foreign key for the model there

Comment: Basically, my problem is that I am looping through the formset and calling ```save()``` on each. But it is only saving that last iteration of the loop

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I had made a switch to make the foreign key the primary key. And so the loop could only have one instance since primary keys can't be repeated. Stupid mistake on my part