# Django - Form value ERROR [Simple?]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I will provide all the details necessary to this issue.

Issue description:

- I store some input fields with the Django forms (i.e. `FormPredmet`)
- After that I save the form in a model called > `Predmet`
- When pulling the data I have an issue that I didn't have with **ModelForm**
- When printing or displaying (on the page) the Predmet.predavacIme object I get:

`<input type="text" name="Ime_Predavaca" value="Elvir" maxlength="50" required id="id_Ime_Predavaca" /> <input type="text" name="Ime_Predavaca" value="Elvir" maxlength="50" required id="id_Ime_Predavaca" /> <input type="text" name="Ime_Predavaca" value="Dzenan" maxlength="50" required id="id_Ime_Predavaca" /> <input type="text" name="Ime_Predavaca" value="Petko" maxlength="50" required id="id_Ime_Predavaca" />`

Instead I just wanted a single value of each of these:

Desired output: `Elvir`,`Elvir`, `Dzenan`, `Petko`

Summary:

- I get data using FormPredmet(forms.Form) this is I think the issue
- then save the data to the Model Predmet
- I try getting any obj for instance: myobj = Predmet.objects.get(pk=1)
- after printing one of it's fields print(myobj.imePredavaca())
- Instead of a value like "Elvir" I get HTML..input.. (did I store html?)

## Models`models.py`

```
class ModelRazred(models.Model):
    godina = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    brojRazreda = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ime = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prezime = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Predmet(models.Model):
    predavacIme = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    predavacPrezime = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imePredmeta = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    razred = models.ForeignKey(ModelRazred, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## URLS `urls.py`

```
"""urlconf for the base application"""


from django.urls import path

from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    #Base
    path('', home, name='home'),





    # Stranice
    path('dodajrazred/', dodajrazred, name='dodajrazred'),

    path('predmeti/<int:razred_id>/', predmetisubmit, name='predmetisubmit'),
    path('razred/<int:razred_id>/', detail, name='detail'),

    path('predmetisubmit/<int:razred_id>/', predmetisubmit, name='predmetisubmit'),




    # Metode
    path('predmet_submit/<int:razred_id>/', predmet_submit, name='predmet_submit'),


]
```

## VIEWS `views.py`

```
    def detail(request, razred_id):

    # Funkcija vraca detalje o odredjenom razredu
    # i njegove ucenike?

    form = FormPredmet()
    detaljiRazreda = ModelRazred.objects.get(pk=razred_id)
    form.razred = detaljiRazreda

    predmeti = Predmet.objects.filter(razred__id = razred_id)
    # svi predmeti tog odredjenog razreda 

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'predmeti':predmeti,
        'razred_id': detaljiRazreda.id,
        'ime' : detaljiRazreda.ime,
        'prezime': detaljiRazreda.prezime
    }
```

## Forms `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from .models import ModelRazred, Predmet


class Razred(forms.ModelForm):
    godina = forms.IntegerField()
    brojRazreda = forms.IntegerField()
    ime = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    prezime = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelRazred
        fields = ('godina', 'brojRazreda', 'ime', 'prezime')


class FormPredmet(forms.Form):
    Ime_Predavaca = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Prezime_Predavaca = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Ime_Predmeta = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        model = Predmet
        fields = ('Ime_Predavaca', 'Prezime_Predavaca',
                  'Ime_Predmeta', 'razred')

    def save(self, razredID):

        razredPredmeta =  ModelRazred.objects.get(pk=razredID)
        myModel = Predmet(predavacIme=self['Ime_Predavaca'],
                          predavacPrezime=self['Prezime_Predavaca'], 
                          imePredmeta=self['Ime_Predmeta'], razred=razredPredmeta)
        myModel.save()
```

Comment: Have you looked at Django template docs and used the {{}} notation or looked at the __str__() method for customizing how you want your object to be printed?

Comment: @dfundako Yes, but that would be if I call the whole object (i.e. predmet) I just want one field for instance {{predmet.predavacIme}} and to get "Elvir"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clean form data before you save it into the model. Form returns all data with HTML tags. You can check more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#field-data). In your case you need to do something like this:

```
def save(self, razredID):

        razredPredmeta =  ModelRazred.objects.get(pk=razredID)
        myModel = Predmet(predavacIme=self.cleaned_data['Ime_Predavaca'],
                          predavacPrezime=self.cleaned_data['Prezime_Predavaca'], 
                          imePredmeta=self.cleaned_data['Ime_Predmeta'], razred=razredPredmeta)
        myModel.save()
```

Also I would recommend to move a `save()` method from your `Form` to your `View` - it is more readable to save models there, forms only process form data.

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Note: I did not clean the data when I used (forms.Form). Since I did not have to do that with (forms.FormModels).

Comment: @Elvir Muslic  You did not show the code where you use your `Razred` form, so I cant say why you have not to *clean data* there.  Also read this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926420/8495108 for more info about `cleaned_data` method.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what it was. I couldn't use ModelsForm for this one... Thank you!